# Comments lines of xml

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I want to solve one issue. 
Input is log file. It contains xml file path and line number which causing error.
Want to write java code which will read log file take file path xml type and according to the line no, xml lines must get commented.
Please help.
Thanks and regards,
Keshav

`

Comment: Please add some of your code to your question to help us better understand.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply comment a block of xml nodes via `<!--` and then `-->`

```
<master>
    <child>
    <!--
      this is a commented subchild
         <subchild>
          </subchild>
      -->
     </sub>
</master>
```

Comment: I want to go to specific line of xml and then comment that line using java code